# ReleaseObject Error while exporting into Excel

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, treeview

I have a treeView in WPF.Now as per my requirement i want to export it into excel.I have got a code here in stack overflow 
[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793814/excel-hierarchy-to-treeview-wpf)

Here is my code snippet in c#..

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog browse = new OpenFileDialog();
        browse.Filter = "Excel Worksheets|*.xls";
        if (browse.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range;

            string str;
            int rCnt = 0;
            int cCnt = 0;

            xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(browse.FileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

            TreeViewItem father = new TreeViewItem();

            for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
            {
                for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
                {

                    str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                    if (str != null)
                    {
                        father = new TreeViewItem();
                        father.Header = str;
                        GetChilds(father, cCnt + 1, rCnt, range);
                        treeView_items.Items.Add(father);

                    }

                } break;
            }


            xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
            xlApp.Quit();



            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);
        }
    }

    private void GetChilds(TreeViewItem father, int cCnt, int rCnt, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range)
    {
        int col = cCnt;
        int row = rCnt;
        TreeViewItem child = new TreeViewItem();
        for (; col <= range.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            for (; row <= range.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                string str = (string)(range.Cells[row, col] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                if (str != null)
                {
                    child = new TreeViewItem();
                    child.Header = str;
                    GetChilds(child, col + 1, row, range);
                    father.Items.Add(child);
                }
            } break;
        }

    }
}
```

}

Now in the above code snippet i am not getting how to add ..

```
treeView_items.Items.Add(father);
```

Also i am not able to releaseObject for Excel also and giving error for these lines..

```
releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Please help me .Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you implemented releaseObject method ?

Comment: I am getting error on these lines .Please tell me how to implement it?

Comment: @DhavalPatel Sir How to remove this treeView_items.Items.Add(father); issue sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to release the COM objects in the correct order. I have a helper method in my `ExcelManager` class for this:

```
    private void ReleaseComObjects(bool isQuitting)
    {
        try
        {
            if (isQuitting)
            {
                workbook.Close(false, missing, missing); 
                excelApplication.Quit();
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
            if (worksheets != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheets);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApplication);
            workbook = null;
            worksheets = null;
            worksheet = null;
            excelApplication = null;
        }
        catch { }
        finally { GC.Collect(); }
    }
```

You could optionally remove the `isQuitting` parts of the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot For your solution .Can you point me out how to remove this issue ..treeView_items.Items.Add(father);

Comment: I have no idea what issue that you are referring to, what you are trying to do and what the problem is... I am not a mind reader. Also, why copy code that you don't understand, or even know if it works? You copied that from a question, not even from an answer... that's absolute craziness. The question author posted it because they had a problem with it and you copied it? This question has now been answered, so I'd advise you to ask a new one relating to your other problem and provide as much relevant information as you can.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! for guiding me .I will do the same.Actually i have a treeview in my wpf window.Now i want that treeview to get exported into excel but not getting the way to do it.

Comment: In WPF, we data bind properties to UI controls, so in your case you should have a collection property data bound to the `TreeViewItem.ItemsSource` property and if you did, then all you'd need to do is to iterate through that collection and populate your Excel data from it directly. It's easy when you learn how to code properly and don't copy invalid code. You seriously need to read the [Data Binding Overview‎](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN *before* you return to this website.