# Export WPF Treeview into Excel

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, treeview

I have a TreeView in my WPF application.Now as per my requirement i want to export into Excel format but i am not getting how to start with it.

Here is my TreeView Creation C# Code..

```
private void TreeView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ... Create a TreeViewItem.

        item.Header = "Computer";
        item.ItemsSource = new string[] { "Monitor", "CPU", "Mouse" };

        // ... Create a second TreeViewItem.
        TreeViewItem item2 = new TreeViewItem();
        item2.Header = "Outfit";
        item2.ItemsSource = new string[] { "Pants", "Shirt", "Hat", "Socks" };

        // ... Get TreeView reference and add both items.
        var tree = sender as TreeView;
        tree.Items.Add(item);
        tree.Items.Add(item2);
    }

    private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender,
        RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        var tree = sender as TreeView;

        // ... Determine type of SelectedItem.
        if (tree.SelectedItem is TreeViewItem)
        {
            // ... Handle a TreeViewItem.
            var item = tree.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
            this.Title = "Selected header: " + item.Header.ToString();
        }
        else if (tree.SelectedItem is string)
        {
            // ... Handle a string.
            this.Title = "Selected: " + tree.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Please help me to get it exported into Excel.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Might not be what you want but Excel does accept .csv which would a lot easier

Comment: .@DanielWard OK ,If it is CSV also i have no idea .Please guide me

Comment: The format for .csv is each row separated by a newline and each value in a row separated by a comma (in a plain text file). The first row would be your header values.

Comment: @DanielWard Sir I am very new to technology .Both WPF treeView and CSV is new for me .If you can please guide me with reference of my code .i will be gratefull

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826300/releaseobject-error-while-exporting-into-excel/24826454#24826454), in WPF, we data bind properties to UI controls, so in your case you should have a collection property data bound to the [`TreeView.ItemsSource` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.110).aspx). If you did, then all you'd need to do is to iterate through that collection and populate your Excel data from it directly.

So your first error is trying to populate your `TreeView` from the `TreeView_Loaded` event handler. I already told you what you needed to do, so I'm a bit surprised that you completely ignored my advise and continued along the incorrect path. *Define a collection property to data bind to the `TreeView.ItemsSource` property*... you also need to declare a custom data type class with the required properties, eg. one collection property to data bind to the child node's `ItemsSource` property:

```
public ObservableCollection<YourClass> Items
{
    get { return items; }
    set { items = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Items"); }
}
```

Then we data bind this to the `TreeView.ItemsSource` property:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

Finally, we need to declare a [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) to define what each item should look like:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"> 
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>     
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsPropertyInYourClass}"> 
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameOfPropertyInYourClass}" />     
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>     
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>     
</TreeView>
```

So that's how you display items in a `TreeView` properly... please see the [TreeView and HierarchicalDataTemplate, Step-by-Step](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx) page on MSDN for further help with this.

Now all you need to do is to iterate through your collection to populate your Excel data. Rather than going through all of that code now, I'd rather direct you to read an online tutorial, so please take a look at the [Export data to Excel using C#](http://matijabozicevic.com/blog/csharp-net-development/export-data-to-excel-using-csharp) on matijabozicevic.com.

You still need to read the [Data Binding Overview‎](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further help with data binding.

Comment: I am sorry Sir.Now i am trying to follow step by step ..What to add in get { return items; }
            set { items = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Items"); }

Comment: If you can't understand that, then you really have no purpose asking questions on this website... it is for professional developers, *not* for people who don't know the absolute basics of programming. You can find tutorials online to help you to learn... that is *not* what Stack Overflow is here for. I *was* wondering if you'd understand when I was typing it out.

Comment: *I am sorry sir that i hurt you*... I am unhurt, but perhaps you should read the Stack Overflow [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to find out who can use this website.